# Geometry nodes: How to constraint the selection for "distribute points on faces"?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Goal: I use "distribute points on faces" on a simple plane and want to prevent points from spawning for y>3.

Problem: Why is the nodelogic "position->seperate xyz->compare" not achieving this?
[image]

Image: With this logic I would expect all points for y>3 to disappear but nothing happens

Comment: Is your scale applied on the mesh with the GN modifier?

Comment: If you want to "remove all points..." you would have to use *Delete Geometry* after *Distribute Points on Faces*.

Comment: @quellenform I think they mean like "Remove all points" from the Distribute Points node selection, not like actually remove them entirely.

Comment: @quellenform Im not trying to delete points after they got created. Im trying to put a restriction on the selection of the distribute points node. y<3=true should make it so that there are no points for y>3, right?

Comment: @sinwar Well, in this case it is always a per face selection, because the *Distribute Points to Faces* node works with the faces of a mesh. If the result is not as expected, then Jakemoyo's question is quite justified: Did you scale the object beforehand? Apply the scaling with *Object > Apply > Scale*.

Comment: @quellenform it had nothing to do with the scaling. your answer with delete geometry worked and my logic also worked after creating more faces. see my answer post, thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution A)"delete geometry" works:

[image]

Solution B) The selection of the distribute points node decides if an entire face spawns points or not. so in my example it didnt work because i had 1 large face. creating several new faces with loop cuts and applying the logic makes it work too. (the steps are rougher though, depending on the amount of faces you have):

[image]